# Keep only latest two folders in the directory

Tags: unix, shell-script

I have a directory which has the following folders.

```
Data-2014-07-10-0240
Data-2014-07-10-0340
Data-2014-07-11-1232
Data-2014-07-12-0530
Data-2014-07-13-1210
```

I want to keep only latest two folders and delete the rest. The folder is in this format: `Data-YYYY-MM-DD-HHMM`.

Is there a way around with which I can compare the folder names and keep the latest and delete the rest? I can accommodate this later in my shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the name of the directories is also the time stamp of their creation. If it is like that then you can use **ls** to list files according to the modification time of the directories.

This will list the directories in the order of newest first

```
cd /PATH/TO/PARENT-DIRECTORY/
ls -lt
```

To delete all directories except the newest 2 files:-

```
cd /PATH/TO/PARENT-DIRECTORY/
ls -lt | tail -n +4 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm -r
```

**Note:** First, please try it out in a testing environment and thoroughly confirm if this is exactly what you want to perform also if that script works with your set of directories.

Comment: Thank you. I did it like this, ls -lt | grep "DATA-backup-*" tail -n +3 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm -r . Because my directory has other directories as well like Temp,Abidf,etc. So i did grep on directory which i want and now it is working fine. owever, when i incorporated the same statement in my script it is giving me an Error saying: rm:  missing operand. Any idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: [Nishita Patwardhan](http://superuser.com/users/300750/nishita-patwardhan) I tried out the same thing in a script, it works fine. So I think there is something in your script to which you incorporated.